# Android include layout in portrait and landscape

Tags: android, merge, include

I have activity with layouts for portrait and for landscape.
Each of them includes different balloon.xml

1. For portrait all works fine.
2. For landscape - after test I found that system is including my portrait include :( and all layout is alogned outside visible screen.

Some sample code:
I have two main.xml files - in 'layout' and in 'layout-land' folders.

### main.xml /different content for landscape and portrait/

```
<RelativeLayout
    .......
    <include layout= "@layout/balloon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### and baloon.xml /different content for landscape and portrait/

How to force correct include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. I made some changes. According to google documentation this is very bad, but works.

In portrait main.xml include balloon.xml.
In landscape mainl.xml include balloon_lan.xml.
This fixed problem.
I feel angry because I have to violate correct way of working with resources and in the future I have to remember this hack when have to change code.
Hope program will not crash after android update.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually name both layouts with the same name

**layout-land/baloon.xml**
  and 
l  **layout/baloon.xml****

System automatically finds  wchich one to show.

Comment: Booth have the same name. Booth are included with same include code. During the runtime system will load correct - I agree. for some reasons when compile - I did not see balloon in landscape mode.findViewById retuns correct values. Actually layout is not visible or shown on weird position.